# Configuring Tor browser to exclude exits with "tor" in hostname

Tags: anonymity, security, onion-routing, vidalia, browsers

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Tor Browser to exclude circuits with exit relays whose hostnames contain "tor"?

For example, these exit relays are unwanted:

```
Host Name: arachnidefr94.torproxy-readme-arachnide-fr-35.fr
Host Name: tor-exit.nabnut.net
Host Name: tor18.anonymizer.ccc.de
```

Exit relays such as these are desired:

```
Host Name: atlantic480.us.unmetered.com
Host Name: hosted-by.snelis.com
```

Comment: One could achieve this by hard coding exit relays with "tor" in their hostnames in "ExcludeExitNodes node,node,…". But that would be a long list, and would require getting the nickname for each offending hostname. Or does "ExcludeExitNodes" accept hostnames? Better yet, does it accept wildcards?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it's to avoid blocking. But I doubt that it would help, because some blacklists include all known Tor exit nodes.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the Tor manual I've come to the conclusion that blocking exit relays using a wildcard such as *tor* isn't possible using only regular configuration options.

[It is possible to exclude individually named exit relays](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExcludeNodes), however, using the *ExcludeNodes* or *ExcludeExitNodes* configuration options.
If you try to use a wildcard, however, it fails.

*i.e.*, You can do:

> ExcludeExitNodes tor-exit.nabnut.net

But you can't do [the Tor browser refuses to start]:

> ExcludeExitNodes *tor*

You might want to request this feature on tor-dev.

Comment: One could use a script that: 1) got a list of exit nodes; 2) grepped those containing *tor*; and 3) updated an ExcludeExitNodes line in torrc. But maybe there's a length limit to options specified in torrc?